# Why doesn't this code position the cursor correctly when I build it with Borland C++?

Tags: c, gcc, c++builder, c99, borland-c++

I found this code for a replacement `gotoxy()` function using C standard library only. apparently it compiles using GCC and works like the `gotoxy()` found in `conio.h`.

However I only have Borland C++ v5.5 compiler, this compiles fine but does not reposition the curser like `gotoxy()` in `conio.h` does. Can anybody verify the fact that this works when using GCC or tell me why it doesn't work using Borland?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    printf("%c[%d;%df", 0x1B, y, x);
}

int main()
{
    gotoxy(10, 10);
    printf("hello world");
}
```

Comment: Borland has a `gotoxy()` function available in its copy of `conio.h`.  Why do you need a replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The escape codes being used in your function depend on support being present in your terminal emulator.  It may or may not work, depending on the environment you're using.  For example, your program works as expected in Mac OS X's Terminal application, running bash in xterm compatibility mode.

You can read about [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for more information about this specific case, which is the "HVP – Horizontal and Vertical Position" command.

Comment: If, for example, your standard output is hooked to a printer, it can't possibly reposition the cursor because there is no cursor. What this does depends on the specifics of the terminal you send it to.

Answer (score 3):

That code prints an [ANSI escape sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code): `<esc>[y;xf`, so will only work on an ANSI terminal, or a terminal emulator that supports ANSI codes.

The issue isn't GCC vs BC++, but running in a [unix-style terminal emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) that supports ANSI codes vs the [Windows CMD window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_Prompt).

EDIT: try changing the body of `gotoxy()` to the following. The escape code in your sample moves the cursor to a previous line. The code ending in H should position the cursor to the requested (Y,X) coordinate.

```
printf("%c[%d;%dH", 0x1B, y, x);
```

EDIT2: since the asker is using the Windows CMD console, the correct solution is to use [SetConsoleCursorPosition()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). ANSI escapes aren't supported, or are incompletely supported in Win2k and later.

Comment: you want SetConsoleCursorPosition(), not ANSI escapes. See my updated answer for a link.